# How to collect all user input in one list?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview

This code is for generating multiple `ListTile` each with a `TextField`,
Now I want to collect all user inputs in a single `List`. How can I achieve that? How should I use input controller?

```
ListTile(
  title: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        "Room : ${index + 1}",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 22,
          color: Colors.blue,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 5, 0),
          child: TextField(
            // controller: RoomNameController,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.blue,
              fontSize: 19,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 5),
              hintText: 'Room ${index + 1} Name',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            autofocus: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing you need to do here is rewrite your question follow the [Stack Overflow rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

As you need to do is modify your title, wrap your code and add more specific detail.